# how to overwrite and existing XML file using If Not File.Exists

Tags: asp.net, file, exists, xmlwriter

I'm trying to overwrite an existing XML file.  If the file exists it doesn't get overwritten.  Here I check for it.  Why doesn't it get overwritten.  What am I missing?

Here is my code

```
 Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True

        Dim FilePath As String = "\\server02\me_public$\audits\alert-special-reports.xml"

        If Not File.Exists(FilePath) Then
            Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(FilePath, settings)


            writer.WriteStartDocument()
            writer.WriteStartElement("audits")
            writer.WriteStartElement("alert-special-reports")
            writer.WriteElementString("title", "Alert and Special Reports")
            writer.WriteElementString("rsslink", "http://www.me.org/rss/alert-special-reports.xml")
            While dr.Read()

                writer.WriteStartElement("item")
                writer.WriteElementString("title", dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Title")))
                writer.WriteElementString("description", dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Description")))
                Dim dateNew As String = "", linkNew As String = ""
                Dim DTNew As DateTime
                Dim PDF As String = ""
                DTNew = dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("PubDate"))
                PDF = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FilePath"))
                dateNew = DTNew.ToLongDateString()
                linkNew = "" & PDF & ""
                writer.WriteElementString("link", linkNew)
                writer.WriteElementString("pubdate", dateNew)
                writer.WriteEndElement()

            End While
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()
            writer.Flush()
            writer.Close()
            dr.Close()
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you forgot to close existing open stream. You can try to use the overloaded verion of `XMLWriter.Create` which take `stream` instead of `string` and use the `File.Create` method. Something like the following

```
Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(File.Create(FilePath), settings)
```

Comment: still not working, don't know what i'm missing.  I deleted the file and it copies fine, don't get an error.  It still will not overwrite the file.  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can someone help me with this or anyone know how to use the delet.file?  I've tried this also and nothing.  I'm trying this delete and it is not working.  Dim filePath As String = "\\server02\file$\rss\alert-special-reports2.xml"
        If Not New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath).Exists Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath)
        End If

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It could be some permission issue as you are trying to write to a network location.